# MATLAB: Indexing a large matrix for Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: matlab, indexing

I'm trying to index a large matrix in MATLAB that contains numbers monotonically increasing across rows, and across columns, i.e. if the matrix is called `A`, for every `(i,j)`, `A(i+1,j) > A(i,j)` and `A(i,j+1) > A(i,j)`.

I need to create a random number `n` and compare it with the values of the matrix A, to see where that random number should be placed in the matrix A. In other words, the value of n may not equal any of the contents of the matrix, but it may lie in between any two rows and any two columns, and that determines a "bin" that identifies its position in A. Once I find this position, I increment the corresponding index in a new matrix of the same size as A.

The problem is that I want to do this 1,000,000 times. I need to create a random number a million times and do the index-checking for each of these numbers. It's a Monte Carlo Simulation of a million photons coming from a point landing on a screen; the matrix A consists of angles in spherical coordinates, and the random number is the solid angle of each incident photon.

My code so far goes something like this (I haven't copy-pasted it here because the details aren't important):

```
for k = 1:1000000  
    n = rand(1,1)*pi;  
    for i = length(A(:,1))  
        for j = length(A(1,:))  
            if (n > A(i-1,j)) && (n < A(i+1,j)) && (n > A(i,j-1)) && (n < A(i,j+1))  

                new_img(i,j) = new_img(i,j) + 1;   % new_img defined previously as zeros

            end
        end
    end
end
```

The "if" statement is just checking to find the indices of A that form the bounds of n.

This works perfectly fine, but it takes ridiculously long, especially since my matrix A is an image of dimensions 11856 x 11000. is there a quicker / cleverer / easier way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code as-is will error with out-of-bounds index into `A`.

Comment: You're right - thanks. My actual code takes that into account; I just wanted to get the gist of it across.

Comment: Also, shouldn't you weigh the increment by the number of "hits"? Otherwise, the photon gets multiplied the larger the angle.

Comment: It might be a good idea if you posted a `surf` rendering of `A`.

Comment: Each "hit" corresponds to a photon that lands in that "bin", so the "bins" closer to the center will have more "hits", resulting in a spread most intense at the center.

Comment: Just a sidenote but as you asked for a cleverer way: you may want to reduce the size of A. Think carefully about whether you are really interested in all of those 130 million 'bins'. Perhaps you want to have small bins in the middle and bigger ones near the edges etc.

Comment: @Shash: However, from your definition of `A`, it looks to me that there can be multiple hits for a single photon.

Comment: @Jonas: I tried to be careful not to let that happen; I guess I missed something. I figured that there should be only one "bin" that satisfies the condition that the current random number lies numerically between all four surrounding pixels. If the number is bigger than the next one and smaller than the previous, then that's the only possible "bin".

Comment: @Shash: It's easy to check - simply have a look at the output of the logical statement in my answer for a few random numbers.

Comment: Is there any way of doing this without iterating through the random numbers? That's what's eating up all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the inner loops by performing the calculation on all elements of `A` at once. Also, you can create the random numbers all at once, instead of one at a time. Note that the outermost pixels of `new_img` can never be different from zero.

```
randomNumbers = rand(1,1000000)*pi;
new_img = zeros(size(A));
tmp_img = zeros(size(A)-2);

for r = randomNumbers
    tmp_img = tmp_img + A(:,1:end-2)<r & A(:,3:end)>r & A(1:end-1,:)<r & A(3:end,:)>r;
end

new_img(2:end-1,2:end-1) = tmp_img;
```

/aside: If the arrays were smaller, I'd have used `bsxfun` for the comparison, but with the array sizes in the OP, the approach would run out of memory.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way of doing this while avoiding the iterations through the random numbers? That's what's eating up all the time.

Comment: Not iterating through the random numbers would require a lot of memory - basically you'd create an imageSize-by-#randomNumbers array. I don't think that's feasible in your case.

Comment: @shash: However, if you can tell us more about the structure of `A` there can be cleverer solutions. How do you create `A`?

Comment: There are actually two sets of "A" matrices, one that consists "theta" angles; i.e. the angle between each column and a point at the center of the matrix, a certain perpendicular distance away from the matrix. The other "A" matrix consists of the corresponding row angles. This is hard to explain, but it's just the spherical coordinate representation of each pixel on a "film" (the "A" matrices) with respect to a point source a certain distance away from the film. I made the theta and phi matrices separate for simplicity; dealing with solid angles is a pain.

Comment: So there should actually be two sets of random numbers: one for the thetas and one for the phis, thus defining a random direction taken by each photon.

Comment: I don't think I did a very good job putting that in words, but essentially the difference between any two consecutive rows or columns of A is not constant over the matrix, but it monotonically increases from top-left to bottom-right, just as the matrix values themselves monotonically increase top-left to bottom-right. Since these are all specific angles, I can't make the A values equally spaced.

Answer (score 2):

Are the values in `A` bin edges?  Ie does `A` specify a grid? If this is the case then you can QUICKLY populate A using `hist3`.

Here is an example:
    numRand = 1e
    n = randi(100,1e6,1);
    nMatrix = [floor(data./10), mod(data,10)];

```
edges = {0:1:9, 0:10:99};

A = hist3(dataMat, edges);
```

If your `A` doesn't specify a grid, then you should create all of your random values once and sort them. Then iterate through those values.

Because you know that `n(i) >= n(i-1)` you don't have to check bins that were too small for `n(i-1)`.  This is a very easy way to optimize away most redundant checks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet that should help a lot in the inner loop, it finds the location of the greatest point that is smaller than your `value`.

```
idx1 = A<value
idx2 = A(idx1) == max(A(idx1))
```

if you want to find the exact location you can wrap it with a `find`.

Comment: @Jonas I don't see why it won't work for 2D. If you find a point in idx2 the new value can be either right from it or below it.